# On the correspondence between proof nets and sequents

Tags: lo.logic, monoidal-categories, proof-theory, linear-logic, string-diagrams

**1. Context**
While trying to answer my [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4423085/graphical-calculus-for-star-autonomous-categories) on the existence of a (useful) graphical calculus for star-autonomous categories, I came across the paper [*Natural deduction and coherence for weakly distributive categories*](https://www.math.mcgill.ca/rags/nets/nets.pdf) by Blute, Cockett, Seely and Trimble.
After having defined *circuits* (for given types $\mathscr{T}$ and components $\mathscr{C}$) they look at particular typed circuits, namely *$(\otimes,\oplus)$-circuits with components $\mathscr{C}$ and atomic types $\mathscr{A}$*. Among the components $\mathscr{C}$ are *links* called $\otimes$-introduction and $\otimes$-elimination:

| component links | terminology |
| --- | --- |
| [A,B] $\otimes$I [A $\otimes$ B] | $\otimes$-introduction |
| [A $\otimes$ B] $\otimes$E [A,B] | $\otimes$-elimination |

Pictorially they are represented as follows:
[image]

Blute et al write on page 241:

> Proof theoretically the $\otimes I$ link corresponds to the right-introduction rule for the tensor and $\otimes E$ to the left-introduction rule of the tensor.
> \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{{\Gamma_1\vdash \Gamma_2,A,\Gamma_3}\qquad{\Delta_1\vdash \Delta_2,B,\Delta_3}}{\Gamma_1, \Delta_1 \vdash \Gamma_2, \Delta_2, A \otimes B, \Gamma_3, \Delta_3}(\otimes R)
> \end{equation}
> \begin{equation}
> \dfrac{{\Gamma_1,A,B,\Gamma_2\vdash \Gamma_3}}{\Gamma_1,A \otimes B, \Gamma_2 \vdash \Gamma_3}(\otimes L)
> \end{equation}

**2. Questions**
I do not see how the above links correspond to the given rules of inference. For instance, the $\otimes$-elimination is an elimination rule while $\otimes L$ is an introduction rule.
Furthermore, the two links simply seem a reflection of one another (in their pictorial representation a horizontal reflection) while the rules of inference appear to have a greater structural difference. The right-introduction rule derives from two sequents a third while the left-introduction "only uses one sequent".

- How does the correspondence between the above rules of inference and links look like?
- Does one read the right-hand side of the sequents in the derivation from top to bottom while the left-hand side is read from bottom to top? If so, why?

Answer (score 1):

First, it might be of interest to you to know that Table 1 in [this paper by Dominic Hughes](http://boole.stanford.edu/%7Edominic/papers/freestar/freestar.pdf) compares various diagrammatic presentations of the free *-autonomous category (including the paper you've cited).

As for your concrete questions:

- In these circuits, the inputs at the top correspond to the left of a sequent, while outputs at the bottom correspond to the right of a sequent. The ⊗L sequent calculus rule turns a sequent with A,B on the left into a sequent with A⊗B on the left; this corresponds to taking a circuit with inputs A,B and plugging them into a ⊗E link so that the resulting circuit has an input A⊗B. (There might be some other formulas on the left / inputs of the circuit, which are unchanged.) A similar interpretation can be given for ⊗R: take two circuits, put them next to each other, take the output A from the first and B from the second, and plug them into a ⊗I link with output A⊗B.
- "the two links simply seem a reflection of one another while the rules of inference appear to have a greater structural difference": this is a great point! It is usual in various proof net formalisms — and this applies to Blute et al.'s circuits — that "locally", the link introducing ⊗ and its dual look basically the same (actually, in linear logic the De Morgan dual of ⊗ would be the connective denoted here by ⊕, and you can see here that ⊕I and ⊗I have the same shape). So to distinguish them, one needs to impose an additional condition: a global and combinatorial "correctness criterion", formulated using "switches" which are drawn using arcs in the paper (you can see that there is an arc between the A and B edges of ⊗E, which is not the case for ⊗I).